# C++ difference between unsigned int and unsigned long int

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, g++

I am doing C++ development on Windows with Visual Studio Compiler, specifically Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

For some DSP related work I am using **unsigned int**/**unsigned long** data type. I was wondering what is the difference between these two built in C/C++ type.

I searched through Google and SO for a little bit and found these references.

1. [Types documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) on cppreference.com
2. [Types documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx) on MSDN for Visual Studio 2015
3. [Types documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Integer-Types) for GNU C/C++ (as [G++ compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/support.html#std.support.types.fundamental) stated that C/C++ use same default type implementation, I refer to C doc here)

I assume the cppreference documentation is the summarize for ISO C++11 standard. So from the "standard" **unsigned** and **unsigned int** are 16/32 bits depending on LP/ILP 32/64 data model while **unsigned long** and **unsigned long int** are 32/64 bits depending on LP/ILP 32/64 data model.

For MSDN and GNU documentation they all stated that **unsigned int**/**unsigned long** are using 32 bits implementation and can hold value up to 4,294,967,295. However GNU documentation also stated that according to your system unsigned long could be 64 bits where it is the same as unsigned long long int.

So my question are as follows:

1. For unsigned long 64 bits, is going beyond ceiling 4,294,967,295 an undefined behavior or correct behavior?
2. If I have an application working on Windows system compiled in Visual Studio, basicall **unsigned** == **unsigned long**. True or False?
3. If I have an application compiled by GNU compiler working on Linux/Windows I have to make sure whether **unsigned long** == **unsigned int** or **unsigned long** == **unsigned long long** to avoid data overflow. True or False
4. If I have a cross platform application that might be compiled by all of these Visual Studio/GNU/Clang/Intel compiler I have to clearly classify the environment with bunch of preprocessors to avoid data overflow. True or False

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Thanks for @PeterRuderman pointing out that going beyond ceil value for unsigned type is not undefined behavior.

Then my question 1 will change to:

1. For unsigned long 64 bits, will going beyond ceiling 4,294,967,295 cause itself to wrap around?

Comment: Note that even if `unsigned int` and `unsigned long` happen to have the same range and representation, they're still distinct types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that yes, `sizeof(unsigned)` is not guaranteed to be equal to `sizeof(unsigned long)` but it does happen to be in MSVC.  If you need to know the size of the integer for sure in a platform independent way, then use the types in `<cstdint>`: `uint32_t` and `uint64_t`.  Avoid `long` in portable code, it can lead to a lot of headaches.

Also note that overflowing an *unsigned* integer is not undefined behaviour.  The defined behaviour is that the value wraps around.  (e.g. `std::numeric_limits< uint64_t >::max() + 43 == 42`).  That's not true for *signed* types where overflow is undefined behaviour.

To answer your final question, a 64-bit integer can store values in the range [0, 2<sup>64</sup> - 1].  2<sup>32</sup> + 1 will not cause a wrap around.

Comment: Pretty sure signed overflow is implementation defined rather than straight-up undefined  behaviour. Maybe not **[expr]** note 4 seems to still call it Undefined as of N4594

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Just another question related to this. When we have all of this good data type in <cstdint> library, why do we still need short, int, long and their unsigned corresponding type? Or from another perspective why short, int, long and their unsigned corresponding implementation not following the same rule as types in <cstdint>?

Comment: The types in cstdint are *relatively* new.  The committee couldn't remove the older types without breaking tons of code.  And there are probably still cases where it's better to let the compiler choose your integer size for performance reasons.

Comment: `std::numeric_limits< std::uint64_t >::max() + 42` is `41`, not `42`.

Comment: @user4581301: No, signed arithmetic overflow has undefined behavior (in C it's been that way since the 1989 ANSI standard). Overflow on a signed *conversion* yields an implementation-defined result.

Comment: @yc2986: They serve different purposes. `int`, for example, is intended to be the "natural" size for the machine. You don't always need some specified number of bits. Which type is best depends on the problem you're solving.

Comment: The types in `<cstdint>` are typedef names that name one of the fundamental types. They can't exist without the fundamental types, nor should they. The fundamental types are there to match the underlying hardware, and that's an important performance feature in many applications.

Answer (score 1):

In the C++ standard, `unsigned int` is only guaranteed to be able to represent values from `0` to `65535`.   Practically, this corresponds to 16 bit.  Implementations (i.e. compilers) may provide a `unsigned int` with a larger range, but are not required to.

In comparison, `unsigned long int` is guaranteed to be able to represent values in the range `0` to `4294967295`.   Practically, this corresponds to 32 bit. Again, an implementation may support a larger range.

The ranges and sizes of these types are implementation defined.   The implementation must meet the minimum requirements, and document which it chooses.

It is not uncommon for implementations to provide `unsigned int` and `unsigned long int` that are both 32-bit.   Or, for one or both to be 64 bit.   As you've noted, the documentation for Visual Studio 2015 states that both `unsigned int` and `unsigned long int` represent the values `0` to `4294967295`.

For a compiler like g++, which can target a range of systems, the choices are often determined by the target system.   So a build of g++ for a 32-bit system may support different ranges for `unsigned long` than a build for a 64-bit system.

To answer your questions

> For unsigned long 64 bits, is going beyond ceiling 4,294,967,295 an undefined behavior or correct behavior?

It has well defined behaviour although it may not produce the results you expect.   Unsigned integral types in C++ use modulo arithmetic.  An integral value (of a type that can support a larger range) that is outside the range `0` to `4294967295` will be converted so it is in that range (mathematically equivalent to repeatedly adding or subtracting `4294967296` [note the last digit]).   In other words, it will "wrap around".

> If I have an application working on Windows system compiled in Visual Studio, basicall unsigned == unsigned long. True or False?

Assuming Visual Studio 2015 it is true, as the documentation you have linked to says.   It may or may not be true for future Microsoft products - that is an implementation decision.

> If I have an application compiled by GNU compiler working on Linux/Windows I have to make sure whether unsigned long == unsigned int or unsigned long == unsigned long long to avoid data overflow. True or False

Actually, false.

It is only true if you are porting code that relies on those assumptions being true.

There are techniques you can use so your code does not rely on such assumptions being true.   For example, you can safely detect when an operation involving two `unsigned` values overflows or underflows, and take actions to produce required results anyway.   If all operations are checked appropriately, you can avoid reliance on particular sizes of types.

> If I have a cross platform application that might be compiled by all of these Visual Studio/GNU/Clang/Intel compiler I have to clearly classify the environment with bunch of preprocessors to avoid data overflow. True or False

Not strictly true.    Practically, often true.

If your code sticks to the realms of standard C++, there are techniques to avoid doing that (like I alluded to above, with being able to avoid reliance on sizes of unsigned types).

If your code uses, or provides wrappers for, functions that are outside standard C++ (e.g.  the windows API, posix functions that are not in the C++ standard) then it will often be necessary.   Even in those cases, it is possible to avoid such things.  For example, place versions of function that use the windows API in a different source than versions that use posix.   And configure the build process (makefile, etc) - for example, if building for windows, don't compile or link in the unix versions.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @Peter. I think `unsigned short int` is somewhat intended for a 16-bit data type which range from 0-65535. Just confused on why there is overlap between `unsigned short`, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long` and `unsigned long long`.

Comment: The overlap is historical, and inherited from C.  `short` types (`signed` and `unsigned`) were the "small" types a platform would support, and used to save memory. `long` types were the long(er) type a platform would support. `int` type was the "native" type (e.g. with registers and operations on them implemented in hardware) and, practically, was equivalent to `short` on some machines and `long` on others. Later, more hardware supported 32-bit types natively, so it became more common for `int` and `long` to be equivalent. Then came hardware support for 64-bit, and `long long` types were born

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that (e.g. there are machines, and compilers for them, that work with odd numbers of bits in integral types).   But, in terms of 16 to 32 to 64 bits that sort of thing is the reason for the types, and the overlaps between them.